# How do you hide arrays in the result?

Tags: php, css, arrays, hide

How would I go about hiding these arrays in the result? Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

Below is what i currently have.. I don't want it to show this array mumbo-jumbo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJUrx.png

Here is what I want the result to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud1bn.png

Here is the part of my index.php

```
if(isset($_POST['url']))
{
  include('curl.php');
  include('youtube.php');

  $tube = new youtube();

  $links = $tube->get($_POST['url']);

  if($links) { ?>

  <div id="result"> 
  <b>Download Links  ( Same IP Downloading only )</b> :
  <pre>
        <?php
        print_r($links);
        ?>
        </pre>
  </div>
        <?php } else {

        echo $tube->error;

        }
    }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Here is the part of my youtube.php

```
$formats = array(
        '13'=>array('3gp','Low Quality'),
        '17'=>array('3gp','Medium Quality'),
        '36'=>array('3gp','High Quality'),
        '5'=>array('flv','Low Quality'),
        '6'=>array('flv','Low Quality'),
        '34'=>array('flv','High Quality (320p)'),
        '35'=>array('flv','High Quality (480p)'),
        '18'=>array('mp4','High Quality (480p)'),
        '22'=>array('mp4','High Quality (720p)'),
        '37'=>array('mp4','High Quality (1080p)'),
        );
foreach ($formats as $format => $meta) {
    if (isset($foundArray[$format])) {
        $videos[] = array('ext' => $meta[0], 'type' => $meta[1], 'url' => $foundArray[$format]);
    } 
}

return $videos;
```

Thank you for any help (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with arrays, just print them out in a custom format. Based on what you want the results to look like, I'd suggest a format like this:

```
$format = '<p><a href="%3$s">Download</a> video.%s - %s<br/>Right-click download link and choose etc...</p>';
```

and just pass every item of the `$links` array through it:

```
while($link = array_shift($links))
{
    echo vsprintf($format,$link);
}
```

The snippet above replaces `print_r($links);`. I've tested it with an array like the ones you have:

```
$link = array('ext'=>'flv','type'=>'High Quality','url'=>'http://www.google.com');
echo vsprintf($format, $link);
```

> [Download](http://www.google.com) video.flv - High Quality
> Right-click download link and choose etc...

And that's all there is to it, really. More on `sprint` related functions: [on php.net](http://php.net/vsprintf)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `print_r`. Instead loop over the elements and print them the way you want. You want to do a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop as you've already done in `youtube.php`

```
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
print_r($arr);

Output:
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three )

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}

Output:
Value: one
Value: two
Value: three
```